# Extracting the sequence generated by $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions, partial-fractions

So I need the general formula for the sequence generated by the generating function
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}.
$$
My idea was the decompose this into partial fractions and thus easily deduce the sequence, since the terms would be of the form $\frac{C}{(1-x)^n}$, but I'm left with a term of the form $\frac{x+2}{9(x^2+x+1)}$... How should I proceed?

Comment: A specific trick here is:$$\frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{(x+2)(1-x)}{1-x^3}=(2-x-x^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n}.$$

Comment: In case you are interested, the sequence is the number of solutions of $x+2y+3z=n$, for which you can find many questions and answers [here](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%2B2y%2B3z%3Dn%24&p=1). You could also take a look at [OEIS A001399](https://oeis.org/A001399).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if a generating function has a representation as rational function of the form
\begin{align*}
A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n=\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}
\end{align*}
with $P(z), Q(z)$ polynomials, $\deg Q=q>\deg P$ and
\begin{align*}
Q(z)=1+\alpha_1 z+\alpha_2 z^2+\cdots + \alpha_q z^q
\end{align*} then the coefficients $a_n$ follow the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
a_{n+q}+\alpha_1 a_{n+q-1}+\alpha_2 a_{n+q-2}+\cdots +\alpha_q a_{n}=0\qquad\qquad n\geq 0
\end{align*}
See for instance theorem 4.1.1 in *[Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol. I](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/enumerative-combinatorics-vol-i)* by R. P. Stanley.

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expanded+form+of+%28%281-x%29%281-x%5E2%29%281-x%5E3%29%29), $Q(z)=1-x-x^2+x^4+x^5-x^6$

So, $$a_{n+6}-a_{n+5}-a_{n+4}+a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}-a_{n}=0$$ $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-a_{n-4}-a_{n-5}+a_{n-6}$$ where $a_0=a_1=1$ if you make polynomial divison.

You can check the recurrence relation [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2F+%28%281-x%29%281-x%5E2%29%281-x%5E3%29%29%29)

Answer (score 3):

Let $\tau=2\pi$.

The fraction $\frac{x+2}{9(x^2+x+1)}$ can itself be decomposed with partial fractions:
$$
\frac{x+2}{9(x^2+x+1)}= \frac{x+2}{9(x-e^{i(1/3)\tau})(x-e^{i(2/3)\tau})}=\frac{A}{x-e^{i(1/3)\tau}} + \frac{B}{x-e^{i(2/3)\tau}}
$$
Solving as usual, you get
$$
\begin{align}
A&=\frac{e^{i(1/3)\tau}+2}{9(e^{i(1/3)\tau}-e^{i(2/3)\tau})}& 
B&=\frac{e^{i(2/3)\tau}+2}{9(e^{i(2/3)\tau}-e^{i(1/3)\tau})}
\\
&= i\cdot \frac{-e^{i(1/3)\tau}-2}{9\sqrt 3}& 
&= i\cdot \frac{e^{i(2/3)\tau}+2}{9\sqrt 3}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
[x^n]\frac{x+2}{9(x^2+x+1)}
  &= [x^n]\left(\frac{-Ae^{i(2/3)\tau}}{1-e^{i(2/3)\tau}x}+\frac{-Be^{i(1/3)\tau}}{1-e^{i(1/3)\tau}x}\right)\\
\\&= (-A)[e^{i(2/3)\tau}]^{n+1}+(-B)[e^{i(1/3)\tau}]^{n+1}
\\&= i\cdot \frac{e^{i(2/3)\tau\cdot n}-e^{i(1/3)\tau\cdot n}+2\left(e^{i(2/3)\tau\cdot (n+1)}-e^{i(1/3)\tau\cdot (n+1)}\right)}{9\sqrt3}
\\&= i\cdot \frac{e^{-i(1/3)\tau\cdot n}-e^{i(1/3)\tau\cdot n}+2\left(e^{-i(1/3)\tau\cdot (n+1)}-e^{i(1/3)\tau\cdot (n+1)}\right)}{9\sqrt3}
\\&= \frac{2\sin\left(\frac13 \tau n\right) + 4\sin\left(\frac13 \tau(n+1)\right)}{9\sqrt 3}
\\&= \frac{2\sin\left(\frac13 \tau n\right) + 4\sin\left(\frac13 \tau n\right)\cos\left(\frac13 \tau\right)+4\cos\left(\frac13 \tau n\right)\sin\left(\frac13 \tau \right)}{9\sqrt 3}
\\&= \frac29 \cos\left(\frac13\tau n\right)=\boxed{\frac29 \cos\left(\frac23 \pi n\right)}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: [Indeed](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4824600/timeline#comment_10269733) :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can handle a quadratic denominator by rendering

$\dfrac1{1+ax+bx^2}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n; c_{-1}=0,c_0=1,c_n=-ac_{n-1}-bc_{n-2},$

from which (if the quadratic polynomial $x^2+ax+b$ has distinct roots $\alpha,\beta$):

$c_n=\dfrac{\alpha^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta}.$

With $a=b=1$ and thus $\alpha,\beta=(-1\pm i\sqrt3)/2$, this yields a relatively simple form, to wit:

$\dfrac{1}{x^2+x+1}=(1-x)+(x^3-x^4)+(x^6-x^7)+...$

This is for a numerator of $1$; multiplying in a different numerator is then straightforward.

Comment: I still think that your answer is not helpful. OP is struggling to learn the finer details of solving linear recurrences, so OP could benefit from seeing all of the steps spelled out. However, you pulled that formula for $c_n$ out of nowhere. Are you expecting OP to memorize $(\alpha^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1})/(\alpha-\beta)$, to use next time they encounter a quadratic polynomial i in the denominator?

Answer (score -1):

You also have $\frac k{x+1}$.
If that led to $(-1)^n$ in your formula, you may be happy with $\omega^n$ and $\omega^{-n}$ where $\omega$ is a cube root of $1$.
Instead, if $\frac k{x+1}$ led you to two formulas, one for even $n$ and one for odd $n$, you may be happy with six formulas, one for each value of $n\pmod6$